# Stop iPhone automatically opening airdropped files

Tags: iphone, ios, airdrop

I would like my iPhone 7 running iOS 14.7.1 to not open Photos when pictures are airdropped to it.

How can I disable that behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this as iOS is programmed to automatically open the default handler app after it receives data via AirDrop.